# AAPT: error: resource attr/title_text (aka com.example.DropdownTextView:attr/title_text) not found

Tags: android, android-studio

When I set this code in girdle I face this problem.

```
implementation 'com.github.hakobast:dropdown-textview:0.3.1'
```

and the app doesn't run.

Github link: https://github.com/hakobast/DropdownTextView

Answer (score 1):

As the library owner is not updating the library for the last 1 year I forked it and release a new version on jitpack rather than bintray(jcenter) as bintray(jcenter) is deprecated.

As I don't have paid version of SDK to release on jitpack, you might have to change the dependency name a little as per the jitpack convention which includes the GitHub username.

How to add the new library as a dependency.

- Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

  ```
   allprojects {
   repositories {
       ...
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
  ```

  }
- Add the dependency

  ```
   dependencies {
     implementation 'com.github.dk19121991:DropdownTextView:0.3.3'
   }
  ```

I did try it myself now I am not getting the mentioned error

> AAPT: error: resource attr/title_text (aka
> com.example.DropdownTextView:attr/title_text) not found

Please try the library and let me know, if you feel anything else you need, I just did limited changes and publish it to help you as the owner of the library is not responding

Forked link of library https://github.com/dk19121991/DropdownTextView