# DropDownTextView Android change color

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu

I using https://github.com/hakobast/DropdownTextView in version 0.1.1
version 0.3.1 is not suitable for me.
I'm wondering if it any chance to change the frame colour when I click DropdownTextView.
The second thing is how can I move the DropdownTextView title to the centre?
As you can see I have all gravity in centre mode and nothing happens.

My code:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.*
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.Gson
import hakobastvatsatryan.DropdownTextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var zwrotkaString = """{

}"""
        var stat:Statistic = Gson().fromJson(zwrotkaString, Statistic::class.java)

        val d = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.first_dropdown_text_view_list)

        d.adapter = MyCustomAdapter(this@MainActivity, stat);
    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter(context: Context, stat: Statistic): BaseAdapter()
    {
        val statS:Statistic

        private val mContext: Context
        init
        {
            mContext = context
        }

        init
        {
            statS = stat
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return statS.statisticsForGroups.size;
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any
        {
            return statS.statisticsForGroups[position];
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long
        {
            return position.toLong();
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View
        {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            val rowMain = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlistviewstatistic, parent, false)
            val statDropDownText = rowMain.findViewById<DropdownTextView>(R.id.dropdowntextrow)
            
                statDropDownText.setTitleText("Title")
                statDropDownText.setContentText("Content")

                return rowMain

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    >


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/first_dropdown_text_view_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="20sp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewMain"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.403"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

**rowlistviewstatistic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="qweqdasdasdasdadaq aa fadfeaeef"
        />

    <hakobastvatsatryan.DropdownTextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdowntextrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:content_text_color="@color/purple_500"
        app:arrow_drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow"
        app:title_text_color="@color/colorRed"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:title_text_size="30sp"
        app:bg_drawable_expanded="@drawable/answer_drawable"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**answer_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/answer_border" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the 0.3.1 crash and released 0.3.3 please try and let me know if it fixes your problem.
I am not the owner of the library I forked it and fixed the crash and have to release it on jitpack rather than bintray(jcentre) as it deprecated.

Please find the detail for integrating the library at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520594/4828650

Answer (score 0):

> I'am wondering if it any chance to change frame color when I click DropdownTextView

Add `OnClickListener` to your `TextView` and once the user clicks it change the frame color

```
statDropDownText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     statDropDownText.setRegularBackgroundDrawableRes(R.drawable.answer_drawable)

    }
});
```

> Second thing is how can I move DropdownTextView title to center ?

After going through the source code I found this [method](https://github.com/hakobast/DropdownTextView/blob/master/dropdown-textview/src/main/java/hakobastvatsatryan/DropdownTextView.kt#L156) `getTitleTextView()`.
Calling this will return the `TextView`, and set gravity to center.

```
TextView ta = (TextView) getTitleTextView();
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
ta.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have those options in 0.1.1 version

Comment: @BinaryMan "but I do not have those options in 0.1.1 version" you mean both of them

Comment: statDropDownText.setBackgroundResource()

This is available in kotlin in both version 0.1.1
version 0.3.1 do not work properly for me

Comment: Is getTitleTextView() working for you. Why don't you call it, and use https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932112/9846650 on the textview instead of statDropDownText.setBackgroundResource()

Comment: I chect it and let you to  know

Comment: I face that problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731493/aapt-error-resource-attr-title-text-aka-com-example-dropdowntextviewattr-tit
When I update dropdown... to 0.3.1 version 
Options above are avaiable only  0.3.1 version

Comment: @BinaryMan i think its better to make a github issue

Comment: it is. https://github.com/hakobast/DropdownTextView/issues/14