# implementation 'com.github.hakobast:dropdown-textview:0.3.1'

Tags: android, textview, dropdown

I face this problem:
[AAPT: error: resource attr/title_text (aka com.example.DropdownTextView:attr/title_text) not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731493/aapt-error-resource-attr-title-text-aka-com-example-dropdowntextviewattr-tit)
I found this:
https://github.com/hakobast/DropdownTextView/issues/14
Unfortunately version 0.1.1 do not contain all functions.

If someone know the work-around please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue in 0.3.3 and now `AAPT: error: resource attr/title_text (aka com.example.DropdownTextView:attr/title_text) not found` is not coming.

Please find the detail for integrating the library at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67520594/4828650